# How can I troubleshoot/fix an issue interacting with a running Kubernetes pod (timeout error)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I have two EC2 instances, one running a Kubernetes Master node and the other running the Worker node.  I can successfully create a pod from a deployment file that pulls a docker image and it starts with a status of "Running".  However when I try to interact with it I get a timeout error.

Ex: `kubectl logs <pod-name> -v6`

Output:

`Config loaded from file /home/ec2-user/.kube/config
GET https://<master-node-ip>:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/<pod-name> 200 OK in 11 milliseconds
GET https://<master-node-ip>:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/<pod-name>/log 500 Internal Server Error in 30002 milliseconds
Server response object: [{"status": "Failure", "message": "Get https://<worker-node-ip>:10250/containerLogs/default/<pod-name>/<container-name>: dial tcp <worker-node-ip>:10250: i/o timeout", "code": 500 }]`

I can get information about the pod by running `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>` and confirm the status as Running.  Any ideas on how to identify exactly what is causing this error and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Are you able to kubectl exec into the pod (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) or port-forward to it (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)?

Comment: Though you may also need to look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/ as you may have a node problem

Comment: I am not able to exec to it.  I just tried starting a pod with a basic tomcat image with the command `kubectl run tomcat --image=tomcat:8.0` and when I try to view the tomcat pod's logs or exec I get the same timeout issue.  Think that means there's an issue with the k8s install?

Comment: Yeah in addition to the above 'kubectl get nodes' and 'kubectl get pods --all-namespaces' might help to reveal what

Comment: If that doesn't turn up anything it could be networking issue https://gravitational.com/blog/troubleshooting-kubernetes-networking/

Comment: Could you provide the output of the command <kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide>?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you didn't install any [network add-on](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) to your Kubernetes cluster. It's not included in kubeadm installation, but it's required to communicate between pods scheduled on different nodes. The most popular are Calico and Flannel. As you already have a cluster, you may want to chose the network add-on that uses the same subnet as you stated with `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=xx.xx.xx.xx/xx` during cluster initialization.

- 192.168.0.0/16 is default for Calico network addon
- 10.244.0.0/16 is default for Flannel network addon

You can change it by downloading corresponded YAML file and by replacing the default subnet with the subnet you want. Then just apply it with `kubectl apply -f filename.yaml`